# Не отображать в Alt+Tab

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно скрыть окно из меню Alt+Tab, при этом оставить окно видимым на экране. Такое возможно?

P.S. Перепробовал все способы из гугла, но все они скрывают окно с экрана, а мне нужно, что бы окно осталось.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/551847/6766879